# How to find out where the event is prevented from bubbling up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and I try to submit it but nothing happens. I can see $('#myform').submit() gets called but then nothing happens. I'm guessing that somewhere the submit event is getting caught 'silenced'.  Is there a way for me to find out where this event gets caught?

**update** Darin Dimitrov suggestion helped me to figure out where exactly submit is handled. I was able log handlers for submit events. Then I set break points inside of the handlers and stepped through code to figure out where my submit process was being 'cancelled'.  p.s. I'm looking at log and debugging in firebug of course.

[image]

Comment: Sure there is a way - debugging :) You can also share some of the code here so we could help you better.

Comment: Yup tried debugging. In firebug, right before clicking on submit button, I select 'break on next' option. Then I click submit button, I break inside of jQuery library that deals with focus/blur events. When I step through it it doesn't do anything just exits the function and I'm left with nowhere to go as far as debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out which submit event handlers are registered to your form you could use the following to print them to the console:

```
$.each($('#myform').data('events').submit, function(key, value) {
    console.log(value.handler);
});
```

This obviously assumes that those event handlers have been registered with jQuery.

Comment: At which point would I call this?  On load? On click of the button?

Comment: @dev.e.loper, you could put this code just before manually triggering the .submit event of the form in order to inspect what handlers are registered.